# Why am I getting this error while merging two dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am trying to merge two data frames by column names called "teams".

My merge statement-

```
merge(RB,LB,by.x ="team")
```

The error I am getting is-

> Error in merge.data.frame(RB, LB, by.x = "team") : 'by.x' and 
>   'by.y' 
>    specify different numbers of columns.

```
#Create a data frame to store set of Right-Backs
      RB=data.frame(
       team=c("Liverpool",
     "Manchester United",
     "Chelsea","Atletico Madrid",
     "Juventus",
     "Real Madrid"),
     players=c("Trent-Alexandre Arnold",
        "Diogo Dalot",
        "Cesar Azpilicueta",
        "Keiran Trippier",
        "Danilo","Carvajal")
      ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

   #Create a data frame to store set of Left-Backs
    LB=data.frame(
    team=c("Manchester United",
     "Real Madrid",
     "Liverpool",
     "Chelsea",
     "Juventus",
     "Atletico Madrid"
     ),
     players=c("Luke Shaw","Marcelo","Andrew Robertson","Marcos Alonso","Alex Sandro", "Renan Lodi" ),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
     )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> merge(RB, LB, by = "team")
           team              players.x        players.y
1   Atletico Madrid        Keiran Trippier       Renan Lodi
2           Chelsea      Cesar Azpilicueta    Marcos Alonso
3          Juventus                 Danilo      Alex Sandro
4         Liverpool Trent-Alexandre Arnold Andrew Robertson
5 Manchester United            Diogo Dalot        Luke Shaw
6       Real Madrid               Carvajal          Marcelo
```

Or you can achieve the same result using left_join() from dplyr package.

```
> left_join(RB,LB, by = "team")
           team              players.x        players.y
1         Liverpool Trent-Alexandre Arnold Andrew Robertson
2 Manchester United            Diogo Dalot        Luke Shaw
3           Chelsea      Cesar Azpilicueta    Marcos Alonso
4   Atletico Madrid        Keiran Trippier       Renan Lodi
5          Juventus                 Danilo      Alex Sandro
6       Real Madrid               Carvajal          Marcelo
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to provide both `by.x` and `by.y`, or just use `by`:

```
df <- merge(RB,LB, by.x="team", by.y="team")
df <- merge(RB,LB, by="team")
```

From the reference:

> By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they
>   both have, but separate specifications of the columns can be given by
>   by.x and by.y.

If you don't use `by.y`, the input to `by` equal to `intersect(names(x), names(y))` is used by default. Because `by.x` has only one column and `by.y` - two (i.e., they have different length), the functions terminates.

Comment: Agreed,but  merge(RB,LB,by.x ="players") does not face any issues in the same context!!Also   https://www.guru99.com/r-merge-data-frames.html ,the code from this site worked fine,in contrary to what you explained,slava-kohut/

Comment: @B_man I do get the same error when I run `merge(RB,LB,by.x ="players")`.